# Não consigo salvar no banco de dados em um projeto Spring MVC

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

Eu vou explicar o projeto porque acredito que a maioria das pessoas costumam criar os projetos utilizando XML, e criei o projeto Spring MVC dispensando os arquivos que configuram o projeto como XML.

O problema do meu projeto é que criei a conexão com o banco de dados, criei os métodos do DAO, criei os fomulários em JSP e mesmo assim não consigo inserir os registros no banco de dados.

Bom, vou começar a explicar o projeto;

Esse aqui é a classe `JPAConfiguration`, ele que faz a conexão com o banco de dados dispensando o arquivo `persistence.xml`:

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {



      @Bean
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          em.setDataSource(dataSource);
          em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models" });

          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

          return em;
       }

       @Bean       
       public DataSource dataSource(Environment environment){
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
          dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/casadocodigo");
          dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
          dataSource.setPassword( "123" );
          return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);   
          return transactionManager;
       }

       @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

      Properties additionalProperties() {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
          return properties;
       }
```

Nesta classe acima acredito não ter nenhum problema.

OBS: eu estou seguindo um livro da casadocodigo que ensina Spring MVC. Essa lógica eu tirei do livro, porque eu sou iniciante como programador Spring MVC.

Essa é a classe é `ServletSpringMVC`, ele determina como será a configuração de mapeamento do projeto.

```java
public class ServletSpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{AppWebConfiguration.class, JPAConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
```

Essa classe abaixo indica aonde está o mapeamento das paginas JSP;

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={HomeController.class, ProductDAO.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{




    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Essa é classe DAO, bem simples:

```java
@Repository
public class ProductDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;


    public void save(Product product) {
        manager.persist(product);       
    }

}
```

Essa é minha entidade:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    @Lob
    private String description;
    private int pages;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

}
```

Tudo bem simples!

Estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: estrutura do projeto]

Minha página que estou tentando salvar os produtos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro de Produtos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="/casadocodigo/produtos" >

        <div>
            <label for="title">Titulo</label> <input type="text" name="title"
                id="title" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="description">Descrição</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="description" id="description"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pages">Número de Paginas</label>
            <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Essa é minha página:

[image: Página renderizada]

Quando tento salvar, dá erro 404. Apesar do erro, eu verifico que mesmo tendo gerado o erro, ele se conseguiu salvar, mas mesmo assim não tive sucesso.

*OBS*: Ele somente gera erro na página, mas não notifica erro no console do eclipse.

[image: Console]

Acredito ter feito tudo certo, mas pode ser que eu tenha feito algo de errado, e preciso muito de ajuda para saber aonde estou errando.

Alguém consegue ver algo de errado no código?

Aqui está meu repositório:

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/casadocodigo/tree/master/lojacasadocodigo

Erro:

[image: Página com erro 404]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
                        ATUALIZAÇÃO DA POSTAGEM
```

mensagem exibida pelo log4j;

```
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:40 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class br.com.casadocodigo.loja.conf.AppWebConfiguration,class br.com.casadocodigo.loja.conf.JPAConfiguration]
08:48:40 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@23e1c6ec: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,appWebConfiguration,JPAConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
08:48:41 [localhost-startStop-1] AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
08:48:41 [localhost-startStop-1] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'JPAConfiguration' of type [class br.com.casadocodigo.loja.conf.JPAConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
08:48:41 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@64208072]
08:48:41 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@38b10fea]
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking for request mappings in application context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:40 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controller.HomeController.index()
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/produtos/form],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controller.ProductsController.form()
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/produtos/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controller.ProductsController.save(br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models.Product)
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Looking for URL mappings in application context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:40 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'appWebConfiguration': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'JPAConfiguration': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'homeController': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'productsController': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'productDAO': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'resourceHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'beanNameHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcConversionService': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'handlerExceptionResolver': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcPathMatcher': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcUrlPathHelper': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcValidator': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcViewResolver': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'internalResourceViewResolver': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'transactionAttributeSource': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'transactionInterceptor': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'dataSource': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'exceptionTranslation': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'transactionManager': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'entityManagerFactory': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
08:48:45 [localhost-startStop-1] RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:40 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Looking for exception mappings: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:40 BRST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@70bcac8]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ResourceUrlProvider - Looking for resource handler mappings
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ResourceUrlProvider - No resource handling mappings found
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5694 ms
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Initializing servlet 'dispatcher'
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
out 21, 2015 8:48:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with [servletConfigInitParams]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Oct 21 08:48:46 BRST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@785814ad: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@23e1c6ec
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@7a0438b6]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@4241b627]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@3557ec5]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling provided
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@13cea2d1]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@11255868]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@368d22b8]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@432020c8]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ResourceUrlProvider - Looking for resource handler mappings
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] ResourceUrlProvider - No resource handling mappings found
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcher' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher]
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 46 ms
08:48:46 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'dispatcher' configured successfully
out 21, 2015 8:48:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
out 21, 2015 8:48:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
out 21, 2015 8:48:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 11543 ms
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/lojacasadocodigo/produtos/form]
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /produtos/form
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controller.ProductsController.form()]
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/lojacasadocodigo/produtos/form] is: -1
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'products/form'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/products/form.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/products/form.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'products/form'
08:49:06 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

essa foi a configuração utilizada;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.samples">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.http">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

O que estou precisando é tentar gravar as coisas no banco e não consigo.

poderia me ajuda a ver se existe alguma coisa que indique problemas em inserir o registro no banco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é adicionar uma configuração de log para exibir os erros no console ou num arquivo de log.

Vi no `pom.xml` do seu projeto que está usando o Log4j, portanto isso significa que seria interessante colocar um [`log4j.xml`](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-xml-configuration-example/) na pasta `src/main/resources`.

Sem o erro/exceção alguém poderia apenas tentar adivinhar a causa do problema com poucas chances de acertar.

No entanto, olhando rapidamente algumas classes percebi que você está retornando `products/ok` na listagem, mas não há uma view chamada `ok.jsp`:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class ProductsController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/produtos/")
    public String save(Product product){
        productDAO.save(product);
        return "products/ok";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
    public String form(){
        return "products/form";
    }


}
```

Uma dica: num sistema de verdade, não declare transações nos controladores, muito menos na classe toda.

Não é responsabilidade dos controladores demarcar blocos transacionais. Além do que você acaba colocando transações onde não precisa, como em métodos de consulta ou que nem acessam o banco.

Comment: pode por favor dá uma olhada na minha postagem, pois acabei de atualizar, preciso muito de sua ajuda.

Comment: @wladyband Pelo log parece não está nem passando pelo método `save`. Tente anotar o método com `@RequestMapping(value="produtos", method=RequestMethod.POST)` e veja se faz mais alguma coisa.

Comment: @wladyband Só pra confirmar. O problema agora é que não chega a informação no banco de dados?

Answer (score -1):

Oi, o 404 é porque a página ok não existe. Basta criar... Em relação a annotation @Transactional no Controller, não concordo. O controller invoca vários pontos de negócio da sua aplicação, funciona quase como um service, então faz bastante sentido demarcar a transação ali. Quem controla o escopo de uma transação é quem usa as classes de negócio...

Comment: Num sistema muito simples e sem camadas até funciona, mas se você pretende fazer qualquer nível de separação ou de reuso ou alguma regra maior do que chamar apenas um método de "negocio", isso não funciona. Quem disse que a responsabilidade de demarcação é de quem chama a regra de negócio? Pode ser que seja num nível mais alto da regra de negócio, como no padrão Session Facade. Não inventaram EJBS a toa.

Comment: Só para deixar registrado, o SessionFacade isola a complexidade de várias chamadas de regras, até por isso ele é um Facade... Faria sentido deixar a transação ali. Se você não deixar a transação demarcada em quem controla as invocações, como vai deixar claro que todas elas participam de uma mesma transação?

Comment: Concordo que um padrão como Session Facade é correto para isso, o que eu quis dizer que é errado é deixar isso no controller ou em outra camada da aplicação mais alta que não deveria  saber nada do banco. Acho que no fim isso é apenas um mal entendido de terminologia. Aliás, o voto negativo não é meu.

Comment: Estou voltando essa discussão porque na época, para ser mais exato no mês 10 de 2015 eu ainda estava tentando entender o Spring MVC, então só para REGISTRAR, realmente o @utluiz tem razão em afirma que a anotação '@Transactional' não deve está no controller porque é delegar muita responsabilidade para uma classe só, e não é uma boa prática de programação, com todo respeito, sem querer ataca, pois esse não é meu objetivo, sugiro para Alberto Souza fazer uma atualização no seu livro que é vendido no site da Casa do Código.

Comment: Opa obrigado pelo comentário. Respeito a opinião de todos, mas a minha ainda não mudou. O controller continua sendo um ponto de invocação de sua camada de domínio e não vejo problemas em deixar o @Transactional lá. Caso o(a) programador(a) decida arquitetar o seu código usando o Controller apenas para chamada um service que vai isolar as outras invocações, aí eu acho que pode fazer sentido mover a annotation. Em relação ao livro, agradeço a sugestão, mas vou manter do jeito que está :).